# Exclude results in a list (returned from Get-QADComputer)

Tags: powershell, foreach, quest

## List all active machineaccounts in the current domain

```
$ComputerScan = @(Get-QADComputer -sizelimit $sizelimit -IncludedProperties LastLogonTimeStamp -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -Inactive:$false -OSName $computerFilter | where {$_.AccountIsDisabled -eq $false} )

# Create list of computers
ForEach ($Computer in $ComputerScan){

    $compObj = New-Object PsObject -Property @{
        Computer = $computer
        Credentials = $credentials
        Domain = $domain
      }
      $computers += $compObj
}
```

I am doing a `foreach` on `$computers` after this but I would like to have a exclusionlist..
Preferably formatted like this

```
computer1
server4
computet4
```

But, how?

Greetings from Norway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few improvements to the computer query:

1. LastLogonTimeStamp is returned by default, no need to include it
2. -Inactive is $false by default, no need to specify it.
3. Instaed of using where-object, use ldap filters to get enabled computers

   $computerScan = Get-QADComputer 
       `-LdapFilter '(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))'`
       -Sizelimit $sizelimit -WarningAction SilentlyContinue 
       -OSName $computerFilter | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

Answer (score 1):

```
$ComputerScan = @('blah', 'bluh', 'blih', 'bloh')
$ExclusionList = @('blih', 'blah')

$ComputerScan | where { $ExclusionList -notcontains $_ } | Write-Host
```

Comment: This doesn't work because get-qadcomputer returns objects. Thank you for trying though!

Comment: Can't you filter on one of the properties? $_.Computer or something?